# Request Dispatcher passing

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Hi i am developing a simple hello world application in jsp using spring framework i imported all the packages through the pom.xml to my Dir. Now i am stuck with controller, i am unable to understand how map... Please help me out.
Problem is I unable to pass the message from controller to jsp.
 my controller code and page name is loginaction.java :

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class loginaction {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("message", "Spring 3 MVC Hello World");
        return "loginform";

    }

}
```

My jsp name is loginform.jsp:

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Message : ${message}</h1>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you show us the stack trace ? Did you meet any problems when Manven execute ?

Comment: I guess you have created a web.xml in which you mentioned your mappings such as /*.html, and If you are using convention over configuration then try /loginaction in place of /login way back I did a spring application in which I followed convention over configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use:-

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("loginform");
        modelAndView.addObject("message", "hello world");
return modelAndView;
```

Comment: That is equivalent to what op is doing.